# Vscode atom dark theme not highlighting tkinter

Tags: python, function, tkinter, visual-studio-code, highlight

When I use `from tkinter import *` in vscode with atom one dark theme, I get no highlights from tkinter functions, though my code is still working.

[image]

In the picture, `pack()`, `Tk()`, `Label` and `mainloop()` is supposed to be highlighted (I know this, cause they are in the actual atom software).
Is there anyway to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Solved the problem by using the following code. It highlights functions and attributes.

`
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
      "textMateRules":[{
        "name": "Function call",
        "scope": "meta.function-call.generic, meta.function-call.object, meta.function-call.static",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#61AFEF"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Attribute",
        "scope": "meta.attribute",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#e06c75"
        }
      }, ]
    }
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code editor nor the theme. Its just how most of the theme works. Which part do you expect to be highlighted? All tkinter widgets(`Label`,`Entry`,etc.) are classes, and most themes do not have any highlighting for classes. I don't think much themes would have highlighting on class names and function names as its used very frequently.

> "In the picture, pack(), Tk(), Label and mainloop() is supposed to be highlighted. Is there anyway to fix this?"

"Is supposed to be highlighted" is wrong words to use, as most themes does not highlight classes.

What usually has highlighting is, all the keywords and keyword arguments and string, etc. Since these are highlighted in your code, its working perfectly. I don't think there are any "special effects" for `tkinter`, as any theme for python is same as any theme for `tkinter`.

One way to get your desired effect, is to use a different theme, that actually will highlight classes (maybe monokai or some material themes?). I personally don't prefer alot of theme around, so something like this is perfect. Or the other way is to make or customize your themes, which can mess up the color if you are not sure what your doing.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I know they should be highlighted, cause they are so in the actual Atom software (same goes for editors such as Sublime etc.)

Comment: @Alex Updated for a better understanding

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ended up customizing my theme and found the color code for "functions" that atom uses. I did the same thing for attributes, which was not highlighted either. It works now :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess this is a problem on tkinters part and not the color theme but if it works on other themes and not one dark pro you can always try to change the exisiting colors using "yo generator code"

css-tricks does a good job showing how to install it: https://css-tricks.com/creating-a-vs-code-theme/

Altough they go through how to create your own theme. But you can always choose to import an existing theme.